# Are arrow functions faster (more performant, lighter) than ordinary standalone function declaration in v8?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I am asking this question because I and my colleague have a dispute on coding style because he prefers arrows function declaration:

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
```

And I prefer old-style standalone function declaration:

```
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

My point is that code in old-style more readable and you can more clearly distinguish function and variable declarations. His point is that code with arrow functions just run faster.

Do you know something about actual performance penalties (in v8) when you use old-style standalone function declaration instead of arrow functions? Are that penalties really exists?

Comment: I expect the performance difference will be negligible and vendor dependent. The function body is *run* in the same way. The difference comes in function-object instantiation (eg `prototype` property) and execution context instantiation (e.g. receiver).

Comment: The new way provided by ECMA6 it's just syntactic sugar for the older way. The body is executed exactly in the same way, so there are no changes in performances between these declarations. 
Instead, as outlined by @BenAston, there are differences about the instantiation of the function and the context (e.g. with arrow functions `this` doesn't change context).
About readability it's also habit. Arrow functions seem more complicated to read, but also because we are used to read them in the older way. Also readability it's a point of view.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding vs Arrow-function (in JavaScript, or for react onClick)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375440/binding-vs-arrow-function-in-javascript-or-for-react-onclick)

Answer (score 227, accepted):

V8 developer here. Arrow functions are (mostly) just "syntactic sugar" for conventional function declarations. There is no performance difference.

Comment: Arrow function expressions are more than syntatic sugar. They basically still create `Function` objects by the way. I never read ES6.0 specs. fully (only ES3.0) so what I say may be not exact, but: calling a `Function` constructed by an arrow function expression causes a different value for `this` in its execution context (which is generally said to be the `this` value from the scope chain of the caller).

Comment: @Matheus Which means that when the arrow function uses `this`, it'll need to create a closure. Nothing extraordinary. Also I'd expect the creation of the function *object* to be optimised away in the most cases anyway, so there's likely no gain by not having to create a `.prototype` object either.

Comment: @Matheus: yes, there's a semantic difference around `this`, which is why I wrote "(mostly)". The point of this question (and my answer) is that there's no performance difference -- just like you say, under the hood they're the same `Function` objects, which is why I think it's fair to call them "syntactic sugar". -- @Bergi: Being able to optimize away creation of the function object is the exception, not the rule, unfortunately, because so many things in JavaScript are observable. Closure-heavy programs tend to be quite memory-inefficient for this reason.

Comment: How about the **interpreting time**, not execution time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking -- interpreting is one way of executing. Either way, "there's no performance difference" covers it.

Comment: one thing I still don't understand is, if arrow function essentially is equal to `func.bind(this)`, then wouldn't `.bind()` causes some slow down and extra memory usage as it has to wrap the original function?

Comment: @NormanXu: the implementation of arrow functions doesn't use `.bind()` under the hood, so there is no "original function" to wrap: the arrow function *is* the original.

Comment: @jmrk  Arrow functions are "syntactic sugar" for function expression not  for function declaration.
You can verify with online Babel REPL

Comment: @jmrk but some form of binding `this` to the arrow function/expression as well as swapping `this` for the bound value upon invocation clearly must take place, even if `.bind` is not used, doesn't it?

Comment: @zor-el: sure, `this` is bound (if it's used), just like other variables from the surrounding scope. No additional swapping is needed after that. Essentially `() => this.foo` is like `var that = this; function() { return that.foo; }`. None of this changes the key point: there's no performance difference between arrow functions and regular functions.

Comment: Hey thanks for clarifying, @jrmk. Great insight!

Just to recap then, arrow functions are compiled to closures that implicitly close over `this`, and the compiler replaces all `this` references by references to the closed `this` from the surrounding scope.

I would suggest to incorporate your above explanation into your answer. As it stands, "syntactic sugar for conventional function declarations" can be a bit misleading, whereas your reply clarifies things perfectly.

Comment: @jmrk - Thanks for this. I'm curious if there are indirect improvements (if you have a large number of functions) as a result of not having all of those objects created for the `prototype` property of a traditional function vs. an arrow function? Or are they so small it Just Doesn't Matter™ in the sorts of environments V8 is used in. :-) (Or maybe creating them deferred until/unless they're referenced? Hmmm, I should be able to test that latter question using devtools...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: your last guess is correct: prototype objects are created lazily when needed, so most functions won't have one, and arrow functions don't have an advantage in this regard.

Comment: So I decided to check the V8 code and while spec says there's less to do (no `constructor`, no `arguments`), V8 doesn't actually perform any work unless you actually try to access them. At most it allocates a pointers, which is basically free. https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/b1f450a1a6d0dd3e1ad6d590ea54b12c4ae5d4d0/src/ast/scopes.cc#L2443

Comment: @SaiKiran Babel specifically *does not* use modern JS. That's the whole point of using Babel. What Babel generates is exactly what JS engines *don't* do natively. You cannot compare a compatibility tool with the real thing and think it somehow is the real thing.

Answer (score 10):

I think arrow functions in class properties might cause some performance issue.
Here is an example :

```
class Car {
  setColor = (color) => { this.color = color; }

  constructor() {
     this.color = '';
     this.getColor = () => { return this.color; };
  }

  printCarColor() {
     console.log(this.color);
  }
}
var c = new Car();
console.log(c);
```

If we take a look at the variable c you will notice that function **setColor** and **getColor** are **created brand new for each instance**, and each new copy is placed on each instance whereas function printCarColor is residing on the prototype.

If you want a thousand instances to each be able to make fixed-context method references, you're going to need a thousand separate methods (not one shared), and of course then you're going to have to store each of those thousand separate methods on the instances themselves, thereby defeating the whole point of the single shared prototype.

Comment: I'd actually love to see someone follow up on this with a test.

Comment: While you're right that this is a very inefficient pattern, it has nothing to do with the question, because it's the same for arrow functions and ordinary functions. If you wrote `this.getColor = function() { return this.color; }`, that would be just as bad.

Answer (score 5):

The following shows that:

1. There is a penalty for going first (either traditional or fat)
2. There is no discernible difference in Chrome

```js
function goFat() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        var v = ()=>{};
        v();
    }
}

function goTraditional() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        var v = function() {};
        v();
    }

}

function race() {
  var start = performance.now();
  goTraditional();
  console.log('Traditional elapsed: ' + (performance.now() - start));
  start = performance.now();
  goFat()
  console.log('Fat elapsed: ' + (performance.now() - start));
  start = performance.now();
  goTraditional();
  console.log('Traditional elapsed: ' + (performance.now() - start));
  start = performance.now();
  goFat()
  console.log('Fat elapsed: ' + (performance.now() - start));
  console.log('------');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="race()">RACE!</button>
```

Comment: There’s a massive penalty because you start the first timer before the button is clicked…

Comment: When you don't know what happens behind the scene in v8 (and I really don't know I've read source code of v8, but I don't expert anyway) you can't interpret results in right way because of v8 optimizations. Check this article for some examples http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html

Comment: Fair enough, but if you have to worry about this haven't you already answered your question? If the difference is undetectable in practice then asking about the theory is moot (unless you are interested in the difference in mechanics, which is not what you asked).

Comment: @BenAston I just hope that some guru with deep v8 knowledge will see my question and will give an objective answer. :)

Comment: OK fine. The spec defines the steps taken in the creation of both kinds of function. Some kind of finger in the air "this does more" might also be possible.

Comment: Just throwing out that there's a noticeable difference in FF58. It certainly wouldn't make a difference in everyday usage, though.

Comment: **`There is a penalty for going first (either traditional or fat)`** should be in big bold

Answer (score 5):

I made a short benchmark in jsben.ch. I ran it many times it seems that arrow functions were in the most cases just tiny little bit faster than normal functions. Even once or twice normal function was faster... It looks like the difference is insignificant. So in short - if you don't need to mind **context** or **this**, just use whatever looks better for you ;)

https://jsben.ch/kJxPT

```
const a = (b, c) => b+c;

a(1,2);
```

VS

```
function a(b,c){
    return b+c;
}

a(1,2);
```

[image]

Comment: You're just measuring random noise there. Maybe the ads on jsben.ch got in the way. There is no performance difference between `(b,c)=>b+c` and `function(b,c) { return b+c}`, if your test claims otherwise then your test is lying to you.

Comment: @jmrk yes I mentioned that once the regular function was faster - so: no difference

Answer (score 1):

There are two examples for nodejs:

```
function testFat(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

let testArrow = (a, b) => a + b;

let t1 = process.hrtime();
let tmp1 = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
    tmp1 = testFat(tmp1, i);
}
var fatTime = process.hrtime(t1);
console.log('fat', fatTime);

let t2 = process.hrtime();
let tmp2 = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
    tmp2 = testArrow(tmp2, i);
}
var arrowTime = process.hrtime(t2);
console.log('arrow', arrowTime);
```

````
function testFat() {
    return 0;
}

let testArrow = () => 0;

let t1 = process.hrtime();
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
    testFat();
}
var fatTime = process.hrtime(t1);
console.log('fat', fatTime);

let t2 = process.hrtime();
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
    testArrow();
}
var arrowTime = process.hrtime(t2);
console.log('arrow', arrowTime);```
````

Results are:

> bash-3.2$ node test_plus_i.js
>
> fat [ 0, 931986419 ]
>
> arrow [ 0, 960479009 ]
>
> bash-3.2$ node test_zero.js
>
> fat [ 0, 479557888 ]
>
> arrow [ 0, 478563661 ]
>
> bash-3.2$ node --version
>
> v12.8.0
>
> bash-3.2$

So you can see that there is no difference in function call overhead.

Comment: That is a great answer to the queestion. The overhead of binding  this is probably to small to notice. It would need multiple runs and also runs witht the test loops in reversed order, though. Nobody knows what gc background is going on and messing with the results..

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with [jmrk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44031830/7473935) here but am reinforcing [Rohan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60449045/7473935).

It's worth noting that arrow functions are **not** only "syntactic sugar" when used in ES6 classes.

Arrow functions in classes aren't present on the prototype, but are created as a member for every object, every time that object's class is instantiated.

For example, take this class:

```js
class ArrowFunctionMember {
    i = 0;

    test = () => {
        this.i += 1;
    }
}
```

That's the equivalent of doing:

```js
class ArrowFunctionMemberEquivalent {
    i = 0;

    constructor () {
        this.test = function () {
            this.i += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

It's much easier to spot what's going on in the second example - When the class is instantiated an instance of the `test` function is created with it, this can lead to much larger memory consumption (and will be inherently slower to instantiate) depending on how many objects are created.

Here's a [test](https://jsbench.me/pol4cphvy0/1) I made to illustrate the performance difference between instantiation speed of classes with arrow function members vs with regular function members.

So if you're not creating many objects from classes with arrow function members, the performance difference will likely be negligible. However, if you are creating a large amount of objects then consider using regular member functions instead, so you can take advantage of the prototype sharing that JavaScript objects use.

Comment: A few notes: (1) what you wrote here doesn't match your test: both cases you wrote here are equally bad, as both create a new function for every instance. (2) This has nothing to do with arrow or ordinary functions, if you wrote `this.test = function() { this.i += 1; }` that would be just as bad. (3) There are no ES5 classes at all, classes are an ES6 feature.

Comment: @jmrk, the tests show the difference between instantiation speed for classes with arrow functions vs regular functions, isn't that the point I'm making? You're correct with 2, but that is exactly what an arrow function class member does as I've already stated, not what a regular function member does. You're also correct with 3, classes are an ES6 feature but they're more or less just functions, no? Either way, I used class syntax for POC - I'll update my answer for clarity.

Comment: my point is: you still write "_arrow_ functions in classes aren't present on the prototype", but that's not because they're arrow functions: your updated snippet shows a regular function that _also_ isn't on the prototype. We're in total agreement that methods should be on the prototype, not on each instance -- but that's a different question from whether arrow functions or regular functions are faster (or have the same performance). (There's also a functional problem with arrow functions on instances btw, which is that they don't work correctly when called from subclasses.)

Comment: @jmrk both snippets are meant to be the same thing, demonstrating why arrow functions aren't present on the prototype (context for people unfamiliar with how arrow functions work in classes). It's not related to the difference in speed of execution - as you've said, that's more or less identical. However, there is a clear difference in the memory implications and instantiation speed of classes that use arrow functions vs classes that don't, which _is_ relevant. I've not encountered that functional problem before though, I guess that's to do with context of the function when it's created?

Comment: Again, you can put an arrow function on a prototype (though that causes issues: try `MyClass.prototype.method = () => this.i++` and see what happens), and you can put a non-arrow function on an instance. So "avoid arrow functions in classes" is not a good takeaway for avoiding the pitfall; "avoid putting (any!) functions on instances" is.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it helped me to understand the underlying problem, even if it didn't actually come from the arrow function being an arrow function. For someone who's pretty new to Javascript, the accepted answer is very vague.

Answer (score 0):

in my exp I have found that arrow functions do run faster than normal JS functions.
Here is a small snippet in react which uses arrow and normal function. I found that the component using arrow functions runs a bit faster than the one having normal js function.

https://codepen.io/lokeshpathrabe/pen/qgzadx

```
class Fun extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {start: new Date().getTime(),
                 end: new Date().getTime(),
                 number: 0};
    console.log('Function start: ', this.state.start);
    const fun = function(me){
      let n = me.state.number
      me.setState({
        ...me.state, end: new Date().getTime(), number: ++n
      })
    }
    this.interval = setInterval(fun, 1, this);
  }

  stop(){
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    if((this.state.end - this.state.start) > 5000){
      console.log('Function end: ', this.state.end);
      clearInterval(this.interval)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Counter with Function {this.state.number}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Arrow extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {start: new Date().getTime(),
                 end: new Date().getTime(),
                 number: 0};
    console.log('Arrow start: ', this.state.start);
    this.interval = setInterval(()=>{
      let n = this.state.number
      this.setState({
        ...this.state, end: new Date().getTime(), number: ++n
      })
    }, 1);
  }

  stop(){
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    if((this.state.end - this.state.start) > 5000){
      console.log('Arrow end: ', this.state.end);
      clearInterval(this.interval)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Counter with Arrow {this.state.number}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class HOC extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (<div>
        <h1>The one reaching higher count wins</h1>
        <Arrow/>
        <Fun/>
        </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HOC />, document.getElementById('react-content'))
```

Do let me know if your opinion differ

Answer (score 0):

An arrow function is just a function expression. The below are equal:

```
const foo = (a, b) => a + b // foo = an anonymous function
const foo = function(a, b) { return a + b; }
const foo = new Function("a", "b", "return a + b")
```

A function declaration can be hoisted:

```
function foo(a, b) { return a + b; }
```

An arrow function cannot be use as an generator function like:

```
function* foo(a, b) {
  yield a;
  yield b;
}
```

Consider to use them when your functions need `this` keyword.

---

There are at least not many differences in the performance.