# Are these 2 JavaScript statements equivalent?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, javascript-function-declaration

These 2 statements seem to do the same thing.

```
const handleClick = () => alert('foo');
```

and

```
function handleClick() {
    alert('foo');
}
```

Are they identical and just syntactically different? The first one looks like a variable declaration, whereas the second one is clearly a function definition.

Comment: Have you read on MDN the differences between Regular functions and Arrow functions? Specially for the ones that use implicit return

Comment: They do absolutely the same thing, and they are the same. The first one is trivial function, the second one is so called arrow function from ES6 specification.

Comment: @Gorynych, they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same thing. [The arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) has some limitations:

- Does not have its own bindings to this or super, and should not be
  used as methods.
- Does not have new.target keyword.
- Not suitable for
  call, apply and bind methods, which generally rely on establishing a
  scope.
- Can not be used as constructors.
- Can not use yield, within its
  body.

Comment: This makes it look arrow functions have less functionality, so why were they invented?

Comment: @JSNinja one of the top reasons is to solve a "problem" with `this` property. The arrow function doesn't have its own `this` property. Thus, you directly access the `this` of the outer function scope from the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 arrow functions provide you with an alternative way to write a shorter syntax compared to the function expression. There is no performance difference.

[Are arrow functions faster (more performant, lighter) than ordinary standalone function declaration in v8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030645/are-arrow-functions-faster-more-performant-lighter-than-ordinary-standalone-f)